# Using def and return in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to use def and return in python 3, which will check if a number is higher than another and then return status as either True or False. However, i can't seem to make this work. When i run it, i get a nameError. The code is like this:

```
on_off_status=600

def Status(data):
    if data <= on_off_status:
        status = True
    elif data > on_off_status:
         status = False
    return (status)


while True:
    data=int(input("what is the status?: "))
    Status(data)

    print (status)
```

I want to be able to use the status as True or False in another piece of code, which comes later.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to assign the return value of the function call: `status = Status(data)`

Comment: And just a tip: you can change your whole `Status` method to simply `return data <= on_off_status`

Comment: Or just replace the `elif data > on_off_status:` line with a simple `else:` at least.

Comment: and next tip, to one above: function names shouldn't be started from the capital letter  (if any other will read that code, he will think that this is a class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to receive the returned value from the function.

```
on_off_status = 600

def Status (data):
    if data <= on_off_status:
        status = True
    elif data > on_off_status:
        status = False
    return (status)


while True:
    data = int(input("what is the status?: "))
    status = Status(data)
    print (status)
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
data = int(input("what is the status?: "))
```

you assign an expression (i.e. the object returned by `int()`)
to the name `data`, which is created ex-novo.

You need to do the same with `status` and assign it the newly created object (returned by the `Status` function)

```
status = Status(data)
```

As with `data`, the line above creates the name `status` and makes it refer to the new object.

In your code

```
Status(data)
```

creates a new object, but it is "lost", since you do not write down where it resides, so nobody can reach it via a name (also called variable in other 
languages, more or less).

Then

```
print (status)
```

tries to pass an object called `status` to `print`, but such name was never assigned (i.e. added to the public directory of names, properly called a `namespace`).

Therefore Python cannot find it and throws the `nameError`